# Why do I get an error trying to refer a nested class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, namespaces, nested, nested-class

Why there is an error in the following example?

```
class ClassA
  class ClassB
  end
  class ClassC
    def test
      ClassB.new
    end
  end
end

p ClassA::ClassC.new.test # => #<ClassA::ClassB:0x0000010103f860>

class ClassA
  class ClassD
    def test
      ClassB.new
    end
  end
end

p ClassA::ClassD.new.test # => #<ClassA::ClassB:0x0000010103f010>

class ClassA::ClassE
  def test
    ClassB.new
  end
end

p ClassA::ClassE.new.test # => NameError: uninitialized constant ClassA::ClassE::ClassB
```

Is there another way to create `ClassE`, not by typing `class ClassA; class ClassE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes, if you define your test method to return `ClassA::ClassB.new` :-)

You could also play around with `const_missing` so that it calls `ClassA.const_get`.

Otherwise `ClassB` is not in the current scope, which at that point is only `ClassA::ClassE` and `Object`. When you first open `ClassA`, then `ClassE`, the lookup for `ClassB` is done first in `ClassA::ClassE`, then in `ClassA` (where it is found) and would also look in `Object`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the namespace path? Something like `[:ClassA, :ClassE]`?

Comment: Good question. I don't think the language gives us access to that.

Comment: @Andrei: ah, right. I thought your question was, is there a way that `class A; class B; puts magic end end` would output `[A::B, A, Object]`, while `class A::B; puts magic end` would output `[A::B, Object]`.

Answer (score 0):

The custom `Object#const_missing` method, suggested by [Marc-André Lafortune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312665/why-do-i-get-an-error-trying-to-refer-a-nested-class-in-ruby/3312961#3312961), would be then

```
def Object.const_missing(name)
  @looked_for ||= {}
  key = self.to_s + '~' + name.to_s
  raise "Class not found: #{name}" if @looked_for[key] == key
  return @looked_for[key] if @looked_for[key]
  @looked_for[key] = key
  if self.to_s.include? '::'
    klass = Object
    self.to_s.split('::')[0..-2].each do |klass_string|
      klass = klass.const_get klass_string
    end
    return @looked_for[key] = klass.const_get(name) if klass # klass.is_a?(Class)
  end
  raise "Class not found: #{name}"
end
```

Some related questions:

1. [Does Ruby provide the namespace path, e.g. something like [:A,:B] for class A::B::C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313473/does-ruby-provide-the-namespace-path-e-g-something-like-a-b-for-class-ab)
2. [If I define a class-method in Ruby Object class, how do I get the name of a child class calling this method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314108/if-i-define-a-class-method-in-ruby-object-class-how-do-i-get-the-name-of-a-child)
3. [How do I get class-object from string “A::B::C” in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314475/how-do-i-get-class-object-from-string-abc-in-ruby)