# Does Ruby provide the namespace path, e.g. something like [:A,:B] for class A::B::C?

Tags: ruby, namespaces

Is the following possible?

```
puts A::B::C.new.namespace_path # => [:A,:B], or even [A,B]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe #ancestors is what you're looking for.

So A::B::C.ancestors

or you may just want to `self.class.to_s.split("::")`

Comment: `#ancestors` give me the following array `p A::B.ancestors # => [A::B, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`. The second approach works fine, thanks!