# If I define a class-method in Ruby Object class, how do I get the name of a child class calling this method?

Tags: ruby, class, object, class-method

Example

```
def Object.const_missing(name)
  puts self.class
end
class A; end
A::B # => Class
```

How can I get `A` in `Object#const_missing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def Object.const_missing(name)
  puts self
end
```

Comment: Hehe, embarrassing... Thank you!